# @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm") adding Year to date

Tags: java, date, jackson

I have to format my date to some particular format in my rest api request. For that i am using the @JsonFormat as `@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm")`. I am facing an issue such that if am giving the date as "13/24/2018 10:23" it is converting it into "01/24/2019 10:23" that is adding a year. My requirement is that it gives error we give more than 12 in months.

Comment: Hi Ishant, the `@JsonFormat` annotation is not in plain Java. Are you using Jackson? If so, I would edit your question and add the Jackson tag to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use it:

`@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm", lenient = OptBoolean.FALSE)`

I put `lenient` property to `false`, java doc about this property:

> Property that indicates whether "lenient" handling should be enabled or
>   disabled. This is relevant mostly for deserialization of some textual
>   datatypes, especially date/time types.
>
> Note that underlying default setting depends on datatype (or more precisely
>   deserializer for it): for most date/time types, default is for leniency
>   to be enabled.

You should have this property since jackson `2.9`